# Frappe - Patches do not get executed when installing app

Tags: frappe

We are developing a custom app. The custom app has some patches defined in `patches.txt`.

Now, when we install the custom app on the site, say
`bench --site [sitename] install-app custom-app`
The patches do not get executed even though the `patchLog` table has all the patch entries.

However, when we do `bench migrate` on an existing site
`bench --site [sitename2] migrate`
The patches get executed successfully.
Is this the normal behavior in frappe? How do we get the patches executed when installing the app?

Answer (score 0):

Bench `install-app` command will only install that particular app on the selected site. It will not run any patches during app installation.

This is the default behaviour with most of the web frameworks like Flask, Django.

To run patches/migrations, users have to manually run `migrate` command to run all the pending patches/migrations.